Hamilton ontario 24×24ft shop with 10ft ceiling
I want to build a 24×24 shop with 10ft ceilings.
By code do I need to stud walls with 2×6?

Pretty sure you can use concrete blocks, poured cement, steel framing, timber framing, all sorts of options that are not 2x6 studs.

Also code requirements vary by location, go providing a location would help.

@Milwrdfan That would be Hamiliton, Ontario, Canada Stated in the title other than Canada is assumed to be known to people considering Hamilton, Ontario, which is not in any other country on this planet.

I believe the question, though poorly written, is whether an outbuilding on a residential property in Hamilton, Ontario, built with stud wall construction, must employ 2x6 studs in particular and not 2x4s on the exterior walls.   Perhaps to accommodate required insulation or for other reasons.   I'm assuming a lot but that would be my generous reading of the question.

My knowledge of your building code consists of literally 40 seconds of internet research, but what I have found is that minimum stud size is 38x38mm and minimum exterior wall thickness is 190mm.  This is for Ontario, not necessarily Hamilton.   So you don't have to use 2x6s, but for a hollow wall the normal and practical way to achieve the required thickness while also allowing for appropriate insulation and utilities is a 2x6 inch stud.   With normal facings on both sides that will come to 190mm.   There are also load bearing requirements that might prevent you from faking this with 2x2s although for 24x24 with no upper floor, maybe you could get away with it.  You get the idea.
